# Find the running speed of the student.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

$60$ students are standing in a line with with a distance a $1$ $m$ between each other . The line is moving forward with a speed of $3$ $m/s$ . The last student in the line wanted to convey a message to the first student . So, he ran towards the first student, conveyed the message and returned back to his place . In total he covered $240$ $m$ . Find the running speed of the student .

Since the line is moving forward with a certain speed, the last student must have covered more distance while going towards the first student and less distance while returning back. Which quantity should I consider as the variable?

Comment: Take what is asked, i.e. speed, as variable

Comment: Does the student run with constant speed?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, I think so.

Comment: @Righter I am a bit confused how to form the equations next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let the speed, time spent running forward, and time spent running backward be $s, t_1,$ and $t_2$ respectively.

Then

$(s-3)t_1 = 59.$

$(s+3)t_2 = 59.$

$s(t_1 + t_2) = 240.$

**Edit**
Thanks to Toby Mak for indicating that initially, my first two equations, which specified $60$ on the RHS, were wrong.

Comment: The distance between each student is $1$ m, so your $60$ should be $59$ as there are $59$ spaces between $60$ people.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks for the assist : answer edited.

Comment: The values look a bit strange as you can see on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28u-3%29v+%3D+59%2C+%28u%2B3%29w+%3D+59%2C+u%28v%2Bw%29+%3D+240). They are perfectly plausible however.

Comment: @TobyMak The numbers would have been nicer if there were $(61)$ people.  I wonder if the problem composer made the same initial mistake that I did?

Comment: Thank you @user2661923 for the solution.

Comment: @user2661923 I also think the same. Actually the question which I asked had four choices. If the total students were 61 instead of 60, the quadratic equation would give an answer of $3\sqrt{2}$ which matched one of the choices.